# Querying multiple urls in solr

Tags: solr

My current process:

```
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(“http://localhost:8983/solr”)
SolrQuery parameters = new SolrQuery()
parameters.set("q", *:*)
QueryResponse response = solrServer.query(parameters)
SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults()
```

How do I do this with multiple urls for days of week?
(“http://localhost:8983/solr/Monday”)
(“http://localhost:8983/solr/Tuesday”)
(“http://localhost:8983/solr/Wednesday”)
(“http://localhost:8983/solr/Thursday”)
(“http://localhost:8983/solr/Friday”)

Comment: Do you have different collections for each day ??? Why not have it in one collection and have a field to differentiate the day ? on which you can easily filter and facet on as well ?

Answer (score 1):

By using [DistributedSearch](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) you can send query to multiple url's. Assuming you have following cores :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/Monday
http://localhost:8983/solr/Tuesday
http://localhost:8983/solr/Wednesday
http://localhost:8983/solr/Thursday
http://localhost:8983/solr/Friday
```

You can do it in SolrJ by changing the code as follows.

```
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(“http://localhost:8983/solr/Monday”);
SolrQuery parameters = new SolrQuery();
parameters.set("q", *:*);
parameters.setParam("shards","localhost:8983/solr/Monday, localhost:8983/solr/Tuesday, localhost:8983/solr/Wednesday, localhost:8983/solr/Thursday, localhost:8983/solr/Friday");
QueryResponse response = solrServer.query(parameters);
SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LBHttpSolrServer` class to use multiple urls.

Example:

```
SolrServer solr = new LBHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/Monday",
                "http://localhost:8983/solr/Tuesday");
```